# Why does this use of comma work in a expression but fail in a declaration?

Tags: c, declaration, comma-operator

Am from high level OOP languages C# and Java and recently started scratching my head in C. I feel C a bit weird as equally as one feels JS is. So want to clarify below:

Below gives error and that seems intuitive as it looks like incorrect syntax even in OOP languages

```
int i=0,1,2;  

/*
Error : expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
 int i = 0, 1, 2;
            ^
*/
```

However below works surprisingly:

```
int i;
i = 0,1,2;    //works
```

Why is this behavior? Is their any significance to keep such behavior or just some parsing technicalities?

Comment: @Mahesha999 actually _bigger_ question would be: why on earth you need to write something like that? Grammar says _"declaration \ declaration-specifiers ; \ declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list ;"_, that's all. What do you think it's intuitive (if there is anything _intuitive_ in the comma operator) to write such code?

Comment: @DebasishJana this does not explain why the declaration case does not work as I explain in my answer which no one else seems to have gotten either.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the distinction between `,` in an expression and in a declaration seems have been lost in the answers here which I why I added an answer. That is the interesting part of the question.

Comment: @DebasishJana the conanical C question for how the comma operator works is [What does the comma operator `,` do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1708801) you linked to a C++ question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a tricky question because it relies on the details of the C grammar which is complicated. The best source for understanding it is the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), we can use `Annex A` *Language syntax summary* as a reference.

The basic idea is that:

```
int i=0,1,2;
```

is a declaration and:

```
i = 0,1,2;
```

is an expression.

In an expression we can have the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which evaluates the left hand side(*usually for side effects*), throws away the result and then evaluates the right hand side etc...

In declaration the comma is a grammatical separator not the comma operator. The `,` separates declarators and since `1` and `2` are not declarators in the context of a declaration this is incorrect syntax:

```
 int i=0,1,2;
        ^^^^
```

The relevant grammar from the C99 standard is as follows:

```
init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator   <--- here comma is just a seperator
init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

So in this case the `,` separates *init-declarators* which can either be a *declarator* or a *declarator = initializer* neither `1` nor `2` are *declarators* and so we have incorrect syntax.

It is worth nothing that an *initializer* can be an *assignment-expression* but this expression does not gives us a path to a bare *comma operator*, although we could end up with a comma operator in `()`(*through primary-expression*) but this would not look like a separator.

For the expression the relevant grammar from section `6.5.17` is:

```
expression:
    assignment-expression
    expression , assignment-expression
```

and the description of the *comma operator* is as follows:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point after its evaluation. Then the
>   right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.[...]

Noting that the *comma operator* has the [lowest precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) the following expression:

```
i = 0,1,2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(i = 0),1,2;
```

and so `i` will get the value of `0` and the results of the further evaluations are thrown away.

Comment: +1 I still don't see the point of the question but for sure this answers explaining reasons behind that.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti from what I understand the OP is trying to get why what looks like the same syntax does not work in what seems like similar contexts. If you poke around C or C++ long enough you will find a lot of these oddities that don't have obvious answers.

Comment: well thats precise & I feel all such questions can best explained with  relevant formal grammar specification from the standard. This gives sort of confidence in language behavior. For above, in short, when compiler encounters *declaration* `int...,...` it interpretes `,` as separator and expects *declarators and (optionally) initializers* to surround comma. It found `1` and `2` which are expressions. So it gave error. When compiler encounters *expression*, it interpretes `,` as operator...

Comment: ...What I didnt get is: *The left operand of a comma operator is **evaluated as a void expression**; there is a **sequence point** after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; **the result has its type and value**.[...]*

Comment: @Mahesha999 a void expression is an expression that has type *void* which means its evaluation has limited use except for side effects such as a function which does some other work. It is like casting to *void*.  It is covered in section `6.3.2.2`.

Comment: @Mahesha999 lets says you have `1.0, 2` the operands are double and int the result(*value*) of the comma operator is `2` and the result type is *int*. If on the other hand you had `2, 1.0` the value would be `2.0` and the type would be double.

Comment: The comma operator can be used in a declaration: `int i = (0, 1, 2);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb thank you, I knew I forgot to clarify something, that is now fixed. I meant to clarify that you can not get to a bare `,` but yes you can definitely have a comma operator in `()`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb well I do say *basic idea* and in the following paragraph I do say it is a *syntax error* and I think I do a decent job of explaining grammatically why this is the case. One could say I am using *weasal wording* here but I think I provide enough context for those interested to see the distinction.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour fair enough. I dont think I could say it any better

Answer (score 9):

```
i = 0,1,2;
```

This is assignment, which is equivalent to:

```
(i = 0), 1, 2;
```

The comma operator(which has the lowest precedence) evaluates all operands from left to right, first the assignment `i = 0`, then the expression `1` and `2` and throws the result away.

The second example

```
int i=0,1,2;
```

is initialization. Compare it with the legal initialization `int i = 0, j = 0;`.

It works if you use:

```
int i=(0,1,2);
```

Comment: and it does work with assignment!!! but why??? whats exact specs behind where comma will be allowed or whats allow and not allowed with assignment and initialization?

Comment: what it does in fact is assign to `i` the result of `(0,1,2)`, which is, like `operator,(operator,(0,1),2)`

Comment: @zch even in `int i=(0,1,2)`?

Comment: @qdii, no, I thought you talk about `i = 0,1,2`.

Comment: @zch: all my fault, I used the word "assign" when I should have written "initialized with".

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

```
  int i, j;
  i = 3,0,1,2;
  printf("%d\n", i); => prints 3
```

**2.**

```
  i = 3,j =7;
  printf("%d, %d\n", i, j); => prints 3 and 7
```

`i = 3,0,1,2;` This assigns `3 to i`, then executes `0, 1 and 2`. Check the 2nd example I mentioned.

Also, Try `i=3;0;1;2;` This will not report any error. It will just execute `(i=3), (0), (1) and (2)`.