# Why is it an error to initialize a variable with multiple values using comma operator?

Tags: c

If I write the statement

```
int i=1,2,3;
```

why does here the comma acts as a separator rather than operator since we have comma operator having associativity from left to right  so according to me first value is initialized using `i=1` but it doesn't work like this , what's the reason behind this ?

Comment: see [Why does this use of comma work in a expression but fail in a declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26505722/1708801)

Comment: `int i=1,2,3;` will not going to compile.

Comment: @rakeb.void yes, that is what the question is about

Comment: similar expressions like `int i = 3, y;` would be ambiguous: is it declaring y as an int or part of the initialization?

Answer (score 3):

Because the C language grammar says that an *initializer* must be an *assignment-expression*. The latter includes all expressions *except* those formed from two other expressions and the comma operator:

```
expression :
    assignment-expression
    expression , assignment-expression
```

So `0,1,2` is not a valid initializer for `i`.  Since `1` is not a valid declarator either, this code does not match any syntax rules, making it a syntax error.

I'd guess that the grammar was designed this way on purpose, to avoid the possibility of any situations where a comma is ambiguous between a separator and an operator.